# Oracle SQL having troubles inserting values into a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Trying to insert some values into a table and always showing me some errors, i think it has something to do with the date or smth but not quite sure about that, if anyone knows what's wrong, please let me know...

The error that currently shows me is:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

```
INSERT INTO Cats VALUES ('JACEK','M','CAKE','CATCHING','BALD','2008-12-01',67,NULL,2);
```

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Cats (
    name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_name_nn NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT cat_gen_ch CHECK (gender IN('M', 'W')),
    nickname VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    function VARCHAR2(10), 
    chief VARCHAR2(15), 
    in_herd_since DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE CONSTRAINT cat_inherd_nn NOT NULL,
    mice_ration NUMBER(3),
    mice_extra NUMBER(3),
    band_no NUMBER(2),
    CONSTRAINT cat_banno_fk FOREIGN KEY (band_no) REFERENCES Bands(band_no),
    CONSTRAINT cat_chief_fk FOREIGN KEY (chief) REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
    CONSTRAINT cat_fun_fk FOREIGN KEY (function) REFERENCES Functions(function)
);
```

Comment: `TO_DATE('date-string', 'format_model')`. Make sure date string matches format model

Comment: you should not change your question brutally, on fly. If you have additional problem, ADD UPDATE. Because you just invalidated the answer that was answering your original issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when entering character values for a column whose data type is Date you have to convert it into a DATE by using the TO_DATE function. In you case the column  in_herd_since  is of DATE type , you should try this

`TO_DATE('2008-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -- untested`

```
INSERT INTO Cats VALUES ('JACEK','M','CAKE','CATCHING','BALD',
TO_DATE('2008-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),67,NULL,2);
```